# Jquery check if input is filled, with no submit button

Tags: jquery

I got an input field and I want to check if the respective input is filled with text.  My problem is that I want to add something after the input is filled, (after the input there is no submit button).  How can I do it?

Here's the input :

`<input type="text" class="Textbox" name="shippingZoneZip" id="shippingZoneZip" value="">`

Comment: You could check the value of the input with `focusout` for example

Comment: can you not use .onchange(). Focus out wouldn't tell you if they have clicked in the input and not typed anything on clicking else where

Comment: What's wrong with the `onchange` event???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it by [**keyup**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/). Also it can be checked by [**click**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)`,` [**focus**](http://api.jquery.com/focus/)`,` [**keypress**](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/)`,` [**onchange**](http://api.jquery.com/change/)`,` [**blur**](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) etc events. Example by `keyup`

```js
$('input[name=shippingZoneZip]').keyup(function(){
    alert("The value is " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="Textbox" name="shippingZoneZip" id="shippingZoneZip" value="">
```

**Using [blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)**

```
$('input[name=shippingZoneZip]').blur(function(){
    alert("The value is " + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: The most relevant event seems to be `onchange` event (maybe oninput for more reactive event). BTW, why not just checking for `this.value`?

Comment: I'm kind of noob in jquery and it's my first question here, and I forgot to ask one more thing, is there any way to wait for the user to finish typing and after that to show the alert

Answer (score 0):

The below should work. using the suggestion from twain:

```
$('input[name=shippingZoneZip]').focusout(function(){
    var value=$(this).val();
    if (value.length > 0)
    {
    alert("Message");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use on change event on your text box and check whether value is empty on change of your event and append text.

```js
$('.Textbox').on('change', function() {
  if (!!$(this).val()) {
    // append your text
  }
});
```